# Setting Android fonts locally

Tags: android

I have the following stye code setup,

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

And in the manifest file I have

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

But still when I run the program in Android 4.4.2 Note 3, the comic sans fonts still used, is there any reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to create a typeface class like

```
public class TypefaceClass {


    public static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context context, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                            assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {                     
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

and than Create a font folder in your assets and put your font in that folder. Then setTypeface by using the above typeface class.

```
textView.setTypeface(TypefaceClass.get(context,
                "font/your_font.ttf"));
```

If it doesnot work than Please try to use .otf file instead of .ttf file. It will surely solve your problem. There is some issue with .ttf file from 4.4 above. So try to get the .otf file of font.

Comment: What is the problem with my previous approach? I got it from one of the thread in SO too